# Heroku Shopify App after installation on shop “The page you were looking for doesn't exist.”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, shopify, shopify-app

After creating and deploying a new shopify app - I've installed it to my shop and after installation it redirected me to `home#index` page which in my `routes.rb` for few second and change to another page with `404 - Not found`.

**First view screen for 2 seconds:**
[image: screenshot of the website after the first 2 seconds of loading]

**404 - Not found:**

[image: 404 not found error]

Heroku app logs:

> 2017-08-31T17:03:15.542454+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-08-31T17:03:15.541990 #4]  INFO -- : [b31d1ac2-53c8-4f1d-8c2a-89cb7817bdf9] Started GET "/?hmac=37e4dde7daf5891a1ee93920cdcb02327c0b7f4a44b6d65c601ab08d565a5d49&shop=andreyka.myshopify.com&timestamp=1504198994" for 80.246.140.79 at 2017-08-31 17:03:15 +0000
>
> 2017-08-31T17:03:15.550387+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-08-31T17:03:15.550211 #4]  INFO -- : [b31d1ac2-53c8-4f1d-8c2a-89cb7817bdf9] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
>
> 2017-08-31T17:03:15.550397+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-08-31T17:03:15.550346 #4]  INFO -- : [b31d1ac2-53c8-4f1d-8c2a-89cb7817bdf9]   Parameters: {"hmac"=>"37e4dde7daf5891a1ee93920cdcb02327c0b7f4a44b6d65c601ab08d565a5d49", "shop"=>"andreyka.myshopify.com", "timestamp"=>"1504198994"}
>
> 2017-08-31T17:03:15.557075+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-08-31T17:03:15.556973 #4] DEBUG -- : [b31d1ac2-53c8-4f1d-8c2a-89cb7817bdf9]   [1m[36mShop Load (0.9ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>
> 2017-08-31T17:03:15.987988+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-08-31T17:03:15.987773 #4]  INFO -- : [b31d1ac2-53c8-4f1d-8c2a-89cb7817bdf9]   Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/embedded_app
>
> 2017-08-31T17:03:15.988722+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-08-31T17:03:15.988635 #4]  INFO -- : [b31d1ac2-53c8-4f1d-8c2a-89cb7817bdf9]   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/embedded_app (0.6ms)
>
> 2017-08-31T17:03:15.990684+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-08-31T17:03:15.990595 #4]  INFO -- : [b31d1ac2-53c8-4f1d-8c2a-89cb7817bdf9]   Rendered layouts/_flash_messages.html.erb (0.2ms)
>
> 2017-08-31T17:03:15.991334+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-08-31T17:03:15.991244 #4]  INFO -- : [b31d1ac2-53c8-4f1d-8c2a-89cb7817bdf9] Completed 200 OK in 441ms (Views: 5.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
>
> 2017-08-31T17:03:15.992454+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/?hmac=37e4dde7daf5891a1ee93920cdcb02327c0b7f4a44b6d65c601ab08d565a5d49&shop=andreyka.myshopify.com&timestamp=1504198994" host=blackdiamonds.herokuapp.com request_id=b31d1ac2-53c8-4f1d-8c2a-89cb7817bdf9 fwd="80.246.140.79" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=459ms status=200 bytes=2738 protocol=https

`config.assets.compile = true`

Comment: Is your app setup to be embedded on the shopify partners dashboard?

Comment: It wasn't embedded - so i didn't know in new dashboard this rule! Thank's a lot! It work's)

Comment: I added an answer with a bit more info so people with the issue in the future don't have to dig through the comments for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check to see if your app is setup to be an embeded app in Shopify.

You can do this by going to the [Shopify Partners website](https://partners.shopify.com), clicking your app and then going to the "Extensions" tab. If it is setup correctly you should see a disable button in the "Embed in Shopify Admin" section, if it is not then it will say "Enable" and should just need to be clicked.

[image: Shopify app settings]